Sending two infrared signals one after another with arduino
i'm trying to control my daikin ac (the remotes code is ARC470A1) with arduino. I managed to find the raw IR codes but this time the remote sends two infrared signals one after another. So i tried to replicate that.
Here is my code:
/* rawSend.ino Example sketch for IRLib2
 *  Illustrates how to send a code Using raw timings which were captured
 *  from the "rawRecv.ino" sample sketch.  Load that sketch and
 *  capture the values. They will print in the serial monitor. Then you
 *  cut and paste that output into the appropriate section below.
 */
#include <IRLibSendBase.h>    //We need the base code
#include <IRLib_HashRaw.h>    //Only use raw sender

IRsendRaw mySender;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000); while (!Serial); //delay for Leonardo
  Serial.println(F("Every time you press a key is a serial monitor we will send."));
}

#define RAW_DATA_LEN 12
uint16_t rawData[RAW_DATA_LEN]={
    450, 450, 426, 446, 422, 374, 498, 318, 
    554, 442, 426, 1000};

#define RAW_DATA_LENA 100
uint16_t rawDataA[RAW_DATA_LENA]={
    378, 1366, 410, 1326, 410, 1326, 410, 1330, 
    410, 466, 378, 486, 378, 1362, 410, 462, 
    374, 490, 378, 494, 378, 494, 374, 494, 
    378, 490, 378, 494, 378, 494, 374, 494, 
    378, 490, 382, 490, 382, 1358, 414, 454, 
    414, 458, 414, 454, 414, 454, 418, 1326, 
    414, 454, 414, 458, 410, 458, 410, 458, 
    410, 462, 410, 458, 410, 458, 410, 462,
    406, 466, 382, 486, 406, 462, 394, 478, 
    378, 490, 402, 470, 406, 462, 402, 466, 
    382, 490, 378, 494, 378, 490, 378, 1362, 
    378, 490, 378, 1366, 378, 490, 378, 1358, 
    378, 494, 378, 1000};
   
void loop() {
  if (Serial.read() != -1) {
    mySender.send(rawData,RAW_DATA_LEN,38);
    delay(7);
    mySender.send(rawDataA,RAW_DATA_LENA,38);
    Serial.println(F("Sent signal."));
  }
}

But this didn't work so for debuging it i took another arduino and receive the codes. Other arduino only received the first signal but not the second.

Simultaneous means "at the exact same time", are you sure that you don't mean "2 concurrent signals"? If those signals truly are simultaneous  I don't see how you will ever capture them without threading - which Arduino can't do. They certainly aren't simultaneous with delay(7).

@OysterShucker Sorry for my english. I mean't one after another

Make the delay longer and see if it catches the signal. You might be sending the 2nd signal faster than the first one can be processed. If so, you can either try over clocking your Arduino or use a faster board.

I tried the same on the air conditioner. If the problem was with Arduino, the air conditioner would work. So the problem is with the transmitter.

I'm talking out of my butt here, but maybe there is a way to combine the signals into one send. Like instead of 2 signals, maybe something more like 1 signal with a bit of a dead signal joining them. I doubt this will work, but it's the best I can think of.

Good idea. I'll try

If that has any chance of working, at all, it may depend on how long you make the joining dead signal. Honestly though, numbers are numbers and making the number a lot bigger is not the same as 2 smaller numbers. My idea is actually probably stupid. I just want to help and I don't see anything wrong with your code so, I'm going off on limbs.

I did a little research. The comments in IRLib_HashRaw.h claim 2 things. 1 the code is based on another authors code. 2 it uses sendRaw in the background. If we go to the original authors code for sendRaw it states that you would normally receive the data multiple times and then average it. I believe you have 2 problems. Directly to the AC you are sending the wrong codes, and directly to the Arduino you are sending too fast.

Also, maybe 38khz is not correct. That's actually the default, but there is no guarantee it is the correct number.

If you get desperate you could always use a whack-a-mole solution. Just create some nested loops that try every combination until something works. Also, you may want to consider that the reason these sends are consecutive is because the AC sends the remote a signal saying it's ready for the next code. In other words it's not a delay, it's a response. I'm out of ideas.

Here are the engineering manuals for what I believe is every Daikin AC. If you can find yours it might tell you everything you need to know. I randomly chose one of the manuals just to see the type of data inside. It looks incredibly thorough.
